# C# XML Descending order with elements and attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I need to find the 5 maximum students from a xml file

My xml file looks like this

```
<Professor id="Andy">
<Floor nb="1">
  <data>
    <Room>101</Room>
    <Nbstudent>33724</Nbstudent>
  </data>
      </Floor>
</Professor >
  <Professor id="Mick">
<Floor nb="2">
  <data>
    <Room>102</Room>
    <Nbstudent>33740</Nbstudent>
  </data>
  </Floor>
</Professor >
```

For now my code is

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("student.xml");
var student=
           (from r in xdoc.Descendants("data")
           orderby int.Parse(r.XPathSelectElement("Nbstudent").Value) descending
          select new
          {
           Name = r.XPathSelectElement("//Professor").Attribute("id").Value + "   ",
           Room= r.XPathSelectElement("Room").Value + "   ",
           NB= r.XPathSelectElement("Nbstudent").Value + "    ",
                  })
     .Take(5);
foreach (var r in student)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.Name + r.Room+ r.NB);
            }
```

It does find the 5 value i want but the Name always return the same (even if the data after doesn't belong to this attribute.

I don't know how to do to get the correct attribute.

Comment: all the xml is inside <St></St> but after it's the same and i don't have exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible option to fix the problem with minimal changes to the original code :

```
Name = r.XPathSelectElement("ancestor::Professor[1]").Attribute("id").Value + "   ",
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var student =
(from r in xdoc.Descendants("Professor")
orderby int.Parse(r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Nbstudent").Value) descending
select new
{
    Name = r.Attribute("id").Value + "   ",
    Room = r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Room").Value + "   ",
    NB = r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Nbstudent").Value + "    ",
})
.Take(5);
```

Note that you can simplify the integer parsing like so:

```
var student =
(from r in xdoc.Descendants("Professor")
orderby (int)r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Nbstudent") descending
select new
{
    Name = r.Attribute("id").Value + "   ",
    Room = r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Room").Value + "   ",
    NB = r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Nbstudent").Value + "    ",
})
.Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var student =
   (from r in xdoc.Descendants("Professor")
orderby int.Parse(r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Nbstudent").Value) descending
select new
{
    Name = r.Attribute("id").Value + "   ",
    Room = r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Room").Value + "   ",
    NB = r.XPathSelectElement("Floor/data/Nbstudent").Value + "    ",
})
.Take(5);
```